# How to count pressed keys on FPGA spartan board

Tags: fpga, vhdl, keyboard, spartan

I`m using FPGA Spartan 2 board and want to count the keys pressed from Keyboard
this is my VHDL code :

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY Keyboard IS
 PORT(CLOCK : IN STD_LOGIC;
      RESET : IN STD_LOGIC;
      RK : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 1);
      DE : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 1);
      Invalid_Key : OUT STD_LOGIC := '0';
      Seg1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 Downto 0);
      Seg2 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 Downto 0);
      LEDRow1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 Downto 0);
      LEDRow2 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 Downto 0);       
      Key : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 TO 15));
END Keyboard;

Architecture Behavier OF Keyboard IS
 Signal CLK : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 DOWNTO 0);
 Signal KC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
 Signal KEY_PUSH : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
 Signal KeyTemp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO 16) := "0000000000000000";
 Signal Counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0) := "00000";
Begin
 DE(3) <= '0';
 DE(2 DOWNTO 1) <= KC;
 KEY_PUSH <= KC & RK;

 Process(KEY_PUSH)
 begin
  Case KEY_PUSH is
   WHEN "11101" => --0
    if Counter <= 15 then
      Invalid_Key <= '0';
      Counter <= Counter + 1;
     KeyTemp(conv_integer(Counter)) <= '0';           
    else
     Invalid_Key <= '1';
    end if;
   WHEN "00110" => --1
    if Counter <= 15 then
      Invalid_Key <= '0';
     Counter <= Counter + 1;
      KeyTemp(conv_integer(Counter)) <= '1';
    else
     Invalid_Key <= '1';
    end if;

   WHEN "00101" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 2
   WHEN "00011" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 3
   WHEN "01110" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 4
   WHEN "01101" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 5
   WHEN "01011" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 6
   WHEN "10110" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 7
   WHEN "10101" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 8
   WHEN "10011" =>
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- 9
   WHEN "11011" => -- #
    Invalid_Key <= '1';  -- #   

   WHEN "11110" => -- *
     Invalid_Key <= '0';
    KeyTemp <= "0000000000000000";
    Counter <= "00000";
   WHEN OTHERS =>   
    Invalid_Key <= '0';
  End Case;

   case Counter is
    when "00000" => -- 0
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "00111111";
    when "00001" => -- 1
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "00000110";
    when "00010" => -- 2
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01011011";
    when "00011" => -- 3
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01001111";
    when "00100" => -- 4
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01100110";
    when "00101" => -- 5
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01101101";
    when "00110" => -- 6
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01111101";
    when "00111" => -- 7
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "00100111";
    when "01000" => -- 8
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01111111";
    when "01001" => -- 9
     Seg1 <= "00111111";
      Seg2 <= "01101111";
    when "01010" => -- 10
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "00111111";
    when "01011" => -- 11
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "00000110";
    when "01100" => -- 12
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "01011011";
    when "01101" => -- 13
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "01001111";
    when "01110" => -- 14
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "01100110";
    when "01111" => -- 15
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "01101101";
    when "10000" => -- 16
     Seg1 <= "00000110";
      Seg2 <= "01111101";
    when others =>
     Seg1 <= "00000000";
     Seg2 <= "00000000";      
   end case;

  LEDRow1 <= KeyTemp(1 to 8);
  LEDRow2 <= KeyTemp(9 to 16);  

  if Counter = 16 then
   Key <= KeyTemp;
  end if;
 End Process;

 Process(CLOCK, CLK)
 begin
  IF (Clock'EVENT AND Clock='1') THEN
   Clk <= Clk + 1;
  END IF;    
 end Process;   

 Process(Reset, CLK(10))
 begin
  IF RESET = '1' THEN
   KC <= "00";
  ELSIF (CLK(10) 'EVENT AND CLK(10)='1') THEN 
   KC <= KC + 1;    
  END IF;
 end Process;   
END Behavier;
```

only 1 and 0 keys are acceptable

I want to show counter value in 2 7segment and show the 0 and 1s in two line of LED Matrix, but there a problem on counter, I think the problem is "Key_PUSH" or "RK" are changing many times when I press a key.

How I can create a counter for pressed keys ?

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical switches bounce when they are pressed. Your software needs to debounce the key press before considering it valid. This typically consists of delaying 30-70 ms after the initial key press is detected and checking the switch again. If it is still on, then count it as a switch closure.

Sometimes you may need to wait until the switch is then released (called trailing edge detection) so your logic does not count the same switch closure more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code where you are attempting to make an assignment instead of a conditional evaluation:

> if Counter <= 15 then

I'm assuming this should be:

```
if Counter = 15 then
```

but, I haven't read through the full logic of your code.

Your process sensitivity list needs work.

Also, you'll possibly need to debounce the switch, as stated in the other answer, depending on your clock speed and whether or not it is already debounced on the DSK (or whatever board you're using).